Does Dr. W. Afton show up on day 7 even if he's killed?
On the wiki it says he always shows up on day 7, but does that hold true even if he's killed?

Where do I get this game? It's not on steam or epic for me.

@PenguRoxy it appears to be a browser game, play it here

the browser version if fake, you get the real deal on itch.io

thanks guys :D.

It does, at least in one situation, which is a secret ending, CONSPIRACY THEORIST:

Get to Day 7 with only Dr. W. Afton dying. If done correctly, you wake up in a body bag with Afton staring at you before revealing that he is with the D.D.D.

Here's a video proof:



This proves that Dr. Afton is with the D.D.D., so you can't really kill him.

That doesn't apply if another neighbor is killed too, eg. You let either one of his or Mia's doppelganger in

@Dave this proves that Dr Afton is with DDD, so you can't really kill him, you won't unlock that ending but something different may happen. Btw that's not a reason to downvote my question which is in fact correct, you simply asked if he shows up even when killed and I proved you (at least one situation) he does.

I can kill him by letting in a doppelganger
